# Boost Binary_iarchive from ifStream

Tags: c++, xcode, serialization, boost

I am currently trying to serialize and deserialize objects using boost. My code does not work, so i have simplified the example and i get the EXACT same result. What am i doing wrong here? Boost obviously works.

Includes

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

Codes

```
 std::ofstream outStream(fileName);
 if(outStream.is_open())
 {   
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archiveOut(outStream);
    archiveOut << 1;   
    outStream.close();
 }
```

This bit is calls fine.. The file IS created BUT it is 1.3MB (!?!?!). That somehow seems very wrong.

```
 std::ifstream inStream(fileName);
 if(inStream.is_open())
 {   
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archiveIn(inStream);
    int value = 0;
    archiveIn >> value;   
    inStream.close();
 }
```

The error occurs after the binary_iarchive is instantiated, i can step over this call in the debugger but it crashes on the next step. i.e. After binary_iarchive() but before int value = 0;

```
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archiveIn(inStream);
```

> *** error: can't allocate region
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc:
> std::bad_alloc

I can't quite see what i'm doing wrong here.

The project is built with clang and developed with XCode.

- Are there any common gotchas with boost binary serialization?
- What methodologies would help me undercover what i am doing wrong in this code?

Regards

Note:

Other posts are similar, but not quite this problem. I have tried the solution in the above post.

[Stackoverflow Boost Serialisation Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557090/boostarchivebinary-oarchive-program-crash)

UPDATE

```
bool saveDatabase(std::string fileName)
{
        std::ofstream outStream(fileName);
        if(outStream.is_open())
        {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive archiveOut(outStream);
            archiveOut << 1;
            outStream.close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "ERROR: Could not open file stream to save database";
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For me it created a file with 44 bytes which seems reasonable considering the prelude and tailer that the serialization adds. Can you paste the code used for reproducing the issue as it is ?

Comment: I've added the complete method. It seems it's the saving that is the problem here from what you have said. Clang and Boost, that's my suspicion.

Comment: Even I am using clang, but not xcode. Would be better to step through debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. first

   ```
   archiveOut << 1;
   ```

   You can only use Boost to serialize lvalues. (Look for "stack" in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#objecttracking)
2. next

   ```
   std::ofstream outStream(fileName);
   if(outStream.is_open())
   {
       outStream << 1;
       outStream.close();
       return true;
   }
   ```

   This doesn't even use boost. The file will be 1 byte on most platforms. If not, it wasn't written or you are looking at the wrong file.
3. next

   ```
   else
   {
       LOG(INFO) << "ERROR: Could not open file stream to save database";
       throw;
   }
   ```

   Can't rethrow without a pending exception. [what does "throw;" outside a catch block do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692065/what-does-throw-outside-a-catch-block-do/2692105#2692105)